# How to upload huge files into webserver

Tags: ftp, google-drive-api, sftp, google-drive-realtime-api

I have a virtual machine on google cloud and i create a webserver on this machine (ubuntu 12.04). I will service my website on this machine.

My website shows huge size images which format is jpeg2000. Also my website supports, users can upload their images and share other people. 
But problem is images' size about 1 ~ 3 gb and i can not use standart file upload methods (php file upload) because when the connection gone, that upload starts again. So i need to better way ?

I am thinking about google drive api. If i create a common google drive account and users upload this account on my website using google drive api. Is it will good way ?

Comment: welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask your question is unclear / too broad please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: @DaImTo question is clear and : what is the best way upload huge files (size : 1~3gb) to Google Compute Engine Virtual Machine (Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: Can reword your question maybe should us what you have tried so far and describe any issues you have with your solution.

Comment: @DaImTo i reworded my question again, please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're uploading files to Drive, you can use the [Upload API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) with `uploadType=resumable`.

> [Resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#resumable): uploadType=resumable. For reliable transfer, especially important with larger files. With this method, you use a session initiating request, which optionally can include metadata. This is a good strategy to use for most applications, since it also works for smaller files at the cost of one additional HTTP request per upload.

However, do note that there's a storage limit for the account. If you want have more capacity, you'll have to purchase it.